# Convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Can someone help me how to do the following?

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$, and orthonormal basis $(e_n)$. For $x,y \in H$ prove that the series in the following formula converges, and that

$\langle x , y \rangle $=$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \langle x,e_n \rangle \langle e_n,y \rangle$

where the sum is finite if our basis is finite.

Do you know if for proving that I have to show that

$\langle x,y\rangle=\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{k} \langle x,e_n \rangle \langle e_n,y \rangle \Rightarrow \lim_{k \to \infty} \| \langle x,y \rangle - \sum_{n=1}^{k} \langle x,e_n \rangle \langle e_n,y \rangle \| =0 $

If my thought is correct how can I do that?

Comment: Something seems ill-posed about this question... do you really mean that the inner product is defined that way? or are you trying to say that this sum equals a "generic" inner product? or, are you trying to show that the sum satisfies the properties of an inner product?  It is not clear to me.  Please elaborate.

Comment: This is exactly the question I have to solve. I don't know how to make it clearer, all I can say is that I have to show that the series in the right hand side converges.

Comment: But is the inner product in the space defined to be that series? or are you trying to show that, regardless of what the inner product is, that series happens to also give it to you?

Comment: I think that the inner product is defined to be that series.

Comment: I think not; my interpretation is that $H$ has the inner product structure already equipped, and we want to show that $\langle x, y\rangle$ can be evaluated using the series. Otherwise the series is ill-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing $x$ as a linear combination of basis elements. On the left-hand side, use linearity of the inner product. On the right-hand side, use linearity and orthonormality.

As for convergence, we have the bound
$$
\left|\sum_n \langle x,e_n \rangle\langle e_n,y\rangle \right| \leq \|y\|\sum_n |\langle x,e_n\rangle|.
$$

Comment: Ok I now understand the convergence part! Can you explain in more details how can I do the first?

Comment: If $x = \sum_k a_k e_k$, then $\langle x, e_n \rangle = \sum_k a_k\langle e_k,e_n\rangle$. Orthonormality should be enough to tell you what this is.